# custom view layout_gravity not working when called on another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I created a custom view and when I use it on another layout the layout_gravity on the ImageView is not working.

heres the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="false">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_semi_large"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/card_background_white"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/drawable_padding" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:textColor="@color/warm_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_semi_large"
                android:text="Two line \n Text"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_material"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEzqh.png)

[and this is the output when I use the custom view in another layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhAVu.png)

Comment: I would suggest running it with `Show layout bounds` turned on in developer options.

Comment: and this line to your cardView app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Comment: @TabishHussain added it on my cardView but still not working.

Comment: how do want the output? @Kenneth

Comment: @Athul I want the output to like on the first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Showed Fine For me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="false">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_semi_large"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/card_background_white"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/drawable_padding" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:textColor="@color/warm_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_semi_large"
                android:text="Two line \n Text"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_material"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Pls mention ur padding for ur cardview

Comment: Share the pic how it looks nw

Comment: I can only adjust the padding after u show the pic. and compare the image

Comment: I dont knw the value of ur activity padding

Comment: The padding can also be caused by the recyclerView padding which u hav mentioned in other XML file

Comment: thanks @Athul it works now. I just added the `android:gravity="center_vertical"` on the linear layout inside the cardview.